# Public dataset of cardiac stress test

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a public dataset of data gathered from a cardiac stress test (AKA a cardiac diagnostic test, cardiopulmonary exercise test, or CPX test). Does anyone heard of such a thing?

Comment: This [link](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/stressEcho.html) seems to broken or dead. Deleted the answer.